# Host local USB printer via port 9100 TCP

Tags: windows-8.1, printer, tcp

Is there a way to share a printer plugged into a PC running Windows 8.1 via USB over TCP port 9100? I have a piece of software here that only prints to such network printers and is not capable of printing to a Windows-shared or local printer. Therefore I'd like to have some piece of software that listens to port 9100 and relays the raw printer commands to the locally installed USB printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option is to buy a print server that supports USB, but you will need to check to make sure your software is compatible and that you buy one that allows you to change the listening port if 9100 isn't already the default.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to install a port 9100 print server on the PC. [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rawprintserver/) have one that should do the job. It was last updated in 2013, but only lists support up to XP.